Only change part of the composables by orientation change
Let say I have two composable, one composable want to rotate if the orientation change, another should not recompose by any orientation change, is that anyway to achieve this?
I try many ways but unable to work this out.
Method 1: (change LocalCompositionProvider)

// the one need recompose
Box {}

// the one to force portrait mode
LocalCompositionProvider (
LocalConfiguration provides LocalConfiguration.current.also { it.orientation = Portrait }
) {
 Box()
}

This does not change anything, box2 will recompose anyway.
Method 2 (Rotation)
// the one need to recompose
Box{}


// the one need to keep portrait
Box(Modifier.rotate(-90f)

Unfortunately, the second box has box constrained, the width and the height is still the same before rotation, so it looks like it is cut out.

What is it you are trying to achieve? When screen orientation changes, the ui need to recompose to reflect the configuration change. But you can always control what your UI will look like when it happens. You don't want to recompose because you lost some state?

I want some of the ui rotate based on the orientation, some of them not. The only solution I found it's rotate the composable back.
